# How to retrieve mouse position relative to element

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm getting an issue where event.clientX - getBoundingClientRect.left is returning a negative number. Someone posted a fiddle showing how it's meant to work [Original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wcsovp2/)

```
function getPosition(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = Math.floor(e.clientX - rect.left);
  var y = Math.floor(e.clientY - rect.top);
  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}
```

I updated it slightly to have it reproduce my issue here: [Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wavj768s/)

Mousing over the blue box, I can get -1 to appear. Can someone explain where the rounding error is coming from please.

Comment: If purpose is just to avoid negetive values you can do it by adding `Math.max( ... ,0)`

Comment: In my current implementation that's exactly what I did, but it feels like a hack. I'd like to understand how a event handler that only triggers when I'm over the bound object can return a negative relative position. It's like saying, your mouse was 0.91 pixels away from hitting the trigger zone, but I fired it away, your mouse over the zone is -0.91. Doesn't seem right.